# How is this awk command working across multiple lines?

Tags: awk

I'm confused by a portion of the below command.

```
awk '/<Directory \/>/,/AllowOverride None/{sub("None", "All", $0)}{print}' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf > myfile.txt
```

The command replaces

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

with

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

in the Apache configuration, and writes the updated configuration to `myfile.txt`.

I don't understand how the command is pattern matching across two lines of the file.  None of the examples that I've been able to find work across lines.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the comma in `/<Directory /\>,/AllowOverride`, but I'd like to understand exactly what's going on.  How is this pattern match being done across two lines of the file?

Also, why is `{print}` necessary?  Doesn't `awk` print its results by default?

Comment: Good catch.  I updated the question.

Comment: Address ranges are described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html#Ranges) for GNU awk

Comment: I update my answer with a sample run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- within `/<Directory \/>/,/AllowOverride None/` (between those lines)
- `sub( ... )` will substitute `None` for `All`
- a `{print}` is needed for all lines (substituted or not)

Note that line(s) with `AllowOverride None` will get a `sub` and a `print`, all other line will be printed only.

sample file:

```
<Directory />
   ## we don't want None
    AllowOverride None
   ## all or None-thing
</Directory>
```

will become

```
<Directory />
   ## we don't want All
    AllowOverride All
   ## all or None-thing
</Directory>
```

about default, consider

```
... | awk 'NF==7'
```

which will by default print lines with 7 fields, however, in your case, sub  function overwrite default, so no other action will be taken. That is why you need an explicit print (if you remove explicit print, nothing will be outputed).

Comment: Well, lines with `AllowOverrive None` _which follow a match_ for `/<Directory \/>/` will get `sub`bed.  Since only lines which fall in those ranges will get looked at.

Comment: @DopeGhoti The part I don't understand is how the command specifies that `AllowOverride None` lines that *follow* `<Directory />` lines get substituted.

Comment: @Ben Read the answer carefully: . . . lines between / ... /,/ ... /   it means first regex is matched -> start of action in first { } braces, second regex is matched -> last line is processed. The second { } braces action takes efect for every lines.

Comment: @schweik So is the comma in /.../,/.../ letting you specify a second pattern to match after the first pattern has been matched?  Are the /.../ before and after the comma treated as two separate patterns?

Comment: Yes, it's saying for `/foo/,/bar/ { stuff }` to do `stuff` between a match for `/foo/` and `/bar/`.

Comment: From the man awk: "A range pattern, expr1,expr2 , matches every record between the match of expr1 and the match expr2 inclusively" ()

Comment: If you're interested in playing golf you can replace `{print}` with `1`. This swaps an explicit print with an implied true condition for an implied print with an explicitly true condition.